# Uploading multiple files on WordPress front-end using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I have a custom theme with a front-end form which is used to create a post using Ajax, and it works except for the file uploads.

The form looks like this...

```
<form class="job-form" id="job-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="text" name="job_title" id="job_title" />
    <input type="text" name="job_description" id="job_description" />
    <input type="file" name="job_files[]" id="job_files" multiple="multiple"/>

    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

...and this JS...

```
$('#job-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post( inputs.ajaxurl, {
        action : 'add_job',
        nonce : inputs.nonce,
        post : $(this).serialize()
    },
    function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        ResponseSuccess(response);
    }); 

    return false;

});
```

..and PHP to add everything to the database:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_job', 'wp_ajax_add_job' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_job', 'add_job' );
function add_job() {

    $params = array();
    parse_str($_POST["post"], $params);

    if(isset($_POST["job-form"])) {

        $job_title          = sanitize_text_field($params['job_title']);
        $job_description    = sanitize_text_field($params['job_description']);

        $args = array(
            'post_title'    => $job_title,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_type'     => 'jobs',
            'post_author'   => 1
        );
        
        $result     = wp_insert_post( $args );
        $post_id    = $result;
    
        add_post_meta( $post_id, "job_title" , $job_title);
        add_post_meta( $post_id, "job_description" , $job_description);

        /* If attachments were attached, upload them */
        if($_FILES) {
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

            $files = $_FILES["job_files"];  
            foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {            
                if ($files['name'][$key]) { 
                    $file = array( 
                        'name'      => $files['name'][$key],
                        'type'      => $files['type'][$key], 
                        'tmp_name'  => $files['tmp_name'][$key], 
                        'error'     => $files['error'][$key],
                        'size'      => $files['size'][$key]
                    ); 
                    $_FILES = array ("job_files" => $file); 
                    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {              
                        $new_upload = media_handle_upload($file,$post_id); 
                    }
                } 
            }
        }

        ajaxStatus('job-created', __('Job created.', 'jobs-theme'), $post_id);
            
    }
}
```

When submitting the form, the post gets created along with the meta keys and meta values without any dramas, but **the file attachments are not working**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/198781/wordpress-ajax-file-upload-frontend

Comment: Where is the field named `job-form`? You look for it in the PHP code, but there is no such field either in the HTML or JS. The *form* has the ID `job-form`, but that shouldn’t make its way to the server.

Answer (score 3):

As [jQuery documentation for `serialize` explains](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/),

> Data from file select elements is not serialized.

The reason is that `serialize` encodes form elements into the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, which can only accommodate plaintext string values, and not file uploads. To be able to upload files, you will have to submit the whole form in the `multipart/form-data` format. One way to accomplish it is to use [the `FormData` object](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-formdata); jQuery doesn’t directly support it, but it can accomodate it easily.

Here’s a minimal modification of your code to make this work:

```javascript
$('#job-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // take the data from the form
    const formData = new FormData(this);
    // append further fields
    formData.append('action', 'add_job');
    formData.append('nonce', inputs.nonce);

    $.ajax( inputs.ajaxurl, {
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false, // prevent jQuery from using an incorrect Content-type header
        processData: false, // prevent jQuery from mangling the form data
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            ResponseSuccess(response);
        }
    }); 

    return false;
});
```

The `contentType` and `processData` properties [need to be set to prevent jQuery from mangling the data and adding incorrect headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8244082/3840170).

Because I had to modify the actually-submitted form structure to be able to handle file uploads, the form code and the receiver script will also have to be modified, for example like this:

```html
    <form class="job-form" id="job-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="text" name="post[job_title]" id="job_title" />
        <input type="text" name="post[job_description]" id="job_description" />
        <input type="file" name="job_files[]" id="job_files" multiple="multiple"/>

        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

And in the receiving script:

```php
    # ...
    function add_job() {

        $params = $_POST['post'];

        if(isset($_POST["job-form"])) {
    # ...
```

Here I am taking advantage of PHP’s built-in structural form parsing, where fields with names of the form `a[b]` generate associative arrays that can be accessed as `$_POST['a']['b']` on the PHP side.

Comment: I think it's close. I am now seeing the meta key called `job_files` with this meta value:

```a:1:{s:10:"job_files";a:5:{s:4:"name";a:3:{i:0;s:8:"pic1.jpg";i:1;s:8:"pic2.jpg";i:2;s:8:"pic3.jpg";}s:4:"type";a:3:{i:0;s:10:"image/jpeg";i:1;s:10:"image/jpeg";i:2;s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:8:"tmp_name";a:3:{i:0;s:21:"C:xampptmpphp706A.tmp";i:1;s:21:"C:xampptmpphp706B.tmp";i:2;s:21:"C:xampptmpphp707C.tmp";}s:5:"error";a:3:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;}s:4:"size";a:3:{i:0;i:246961;i:1;i:4684937;i:2;i:1132984;}}}```

But curiously no files are actually being uploaded to the wp-content directory.

Comment: @User_FTW The only strange thing I see is that backslashes appear to be missing from file system paths embedded in the string you gave, and although it looks like output from `serialize`, it cannot be actually `unserialize`d back (the length counter of one string is wrong)

Comment: @User_FTW [`media_handle_upload`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/) can return a `WP_Error`, which you don’t check for. Can you add some code to check it? And does the response contain a `X-WP-Upload-Attachment-ID` header?

Comment: What are you seeing, if any, in the $_FILES[...]['error'] field(s)?

Answer (score -1):

You need to rewrite your ajax request code just like below.

```
var $form = $("#yourFormSelector");
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'url',
    data: new FormData($form[0]),
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(response) {
        //Your response handler code...
    }
});
```

Comment: please make sure contentType is false and processData is false. otherwise files are not send to the server.

Comment: Also the `success` method is now `done`, along with `fail` and `always`.